# Slow query when clicking on category - Why is it querying all products instead of as needed?

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, query, flat-catalog

I've been doing some debugging lately as to why our sites been so slow whenever anyone clicks on a large category. Upon auditing the query being called, I noticed that all of the items were being queried all at once instead of as needed. Below is the query:

> SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (6322, 6325, 9476, 11140, 5259, 5799, 10949, 5803, 10947, 10293, 10953, 5808, 10945, 10292, 5798, 11161, 10946, 5804, 10951, 10950, 5806, 11158, 11159, 11157, 11160, 10948, 10944, 10954, 10974, 10952, 10977, 10975, 5807, 5796, 10988, 10297, 5805, 10963, 8653, 8646, 5801, 8654, 10976, 10972, 5809, 5785, 10152, 5800, 10158, 10994, 10992, 10939, 10725, 10213, 10964, 10212, 10722, 6188, 6193, 6192, 10106, 10724, 6190, 6173, 6198, 6186, 6191, 6189, 6187, 6197, 6195, 8159, 10723, 8163, 10113, 6196, 6185, 8167, 8168, 8166, 8112, 8164, 8169, 8110, 10215, 10720, 10216, 10219, 10114, 5797, 10721, 10719, 11618, 8162, 6171, 8160, 6208, 8165, 6228, 6233, 6174, 6206, 11619, 6194, 6209, 6234, 6207, 11620, 10112, 10117, 10118, 11613, 11611, 6176, 11614, 6231, 6236, 11617, 6232, 8161, 10718, 10214, 10109, 10156, 10161, 11616, 10154, 10969, 10115, 10157, 10221, 10150, 10160, 11615, 10116, 10153, 10296, 8226, 10727, 8108, 10732, 10220, 8283, 10218, 10713, 10814, 8104, 10728, 10792, 8087, 10812, 8282, 8228, 10217, 8083, 8651, 8644, 10211, 10110, 6178, 11623, 10791, 8652, 10742, 6230, 6235, 11621, 6181, 10789, 6238, 6179, 11624, 11612, 11622, 10790, 10741, 6229, 10788, 10739, 10119, 8214, 8261, 8111, 10105, 10787, 8082, 8284, 8230, 8262, 8213, 8245, 8088, 6487, 10985, 8229, 6403, 10793, 6237, 6398, 6394, 10802, 10805, 8642, 13203, 13201, 10811, 13152, 5802, 10159, 13199, 13155, 10120, 13197, 10108, 13202, 10155, 10111, 13198, 10774, 8047, 10819, 10770, 8048, 8174, 6397, 6393, 6410, 6435, 6443, 6399, 6227, 6402, 10715, 6400, 6391, 6396, 6401, 6404, 6392, 10122, 10125, 10192, 10131, 10781, 10782, 10783, 2338, 10801, 10809, 8260, 6361, 8647, 8643, 10147, 10170, 2469, 8109, 8280, 10141, 13154, 6434, 6395, 10149, 13157, 6437, 6442, 13204, 6440, 13153, 6433, 13200, 11647, 13156, 6436, 6409, 6441, 6223, 6366, 6226, 6224, 6362, 6222, 2378, 8232, 8235, 11648, 11631, 11646, 11632, 10129, 8298, 8303, 8220, 10121, 8142, 8147, 6481, 6139, 6132, 6135, 6140, 6131, 6449, 6445, 6172, 6364, 6170, 6446, 6451, 6168, 10205, 10107, 10127, 10130, 10204, 10123, 10133, 10165, 10138, 10202, 13205, 10973, 2377, 10880, 10863, 11203, 10962, 10864, 11204, 10862, 10136, 8144, 8231, 8086, 8175, 8084, 8227, 8173, 8237, 8146, 8149, 8085, 8233, 6183, 6439, 6225, 6438, 6448, 6365, 8236, 8238, 6360, 2380, 2379, 10704, 10911, 10702, 10135, 6134, 10144, 6479, 6137, 10169, 8291, 10295, 8289, 6369, 6278, 6133, 6138, 6136, 6215, 6444, 6213, 6447, 6450, 6177, 11649, 6214, 6175, 6180, 6212, 10794, 10895, 10888, 10893, 10903, 10906, 10904, 10203, 8663, 6363, 6480, 6281, 8140, 8145, 8234, 8143, 8239, 8148, 8217, 8141, 8151, 8215, 11650, 6427, 6420, 6425, 11607, 10178, 10183, 8665, 10142, 10175, 6242, 6247, 11638, 6240, 8645, 6245, 6250, 6243, 6248, 6241, 6246, 6251, 6239, 6244, 8649, 6249, 10844, 6368, 6216, 8669, 8674, 10126, 6482, 6405, 6376, 10957, 11639, 11644, 6150, 10955, 6485, 6478, 11608, 11640, 10200, 199, 193, 198, 6422, 6430, 6428, 6419, 11645, 6407, 6252, 11633, 11606, 11643, 11636, 11641, 11634, 6455, 6182, 6406, 11605, 11610, 11642, 2363, 6316, 6309, 6378, 6383, 6386, 6310, 6315, 6379, 6426, 6308, 6318, 6424, 10737, 10198, 10171, 8091, 8719, 13150, 8279, 10167, 8092, 10172, 8737, 8107, 10128, 6390, 11637, 7637, 6483, 11635, 6375, 6452, 11609, 6408, 6374, 6411, 6456, 10151, 10174, 7645, 8113, 7633, 7632, 7640, 2364, 11175, 10833, 10858, 11178, 6457, 10859, 2470, 6311, 6161, 6385, 10134, 6272, 6319, 10708, 10164, 6307, 6312, 6421, 6431, 6377, 6163, 6387, 10712, 8093, 8281, 8102, 8090, 8216, 6389, 10132, 2479, 6380, 6314, 6317, 6258, 7639, 6261, 6382, 6259, 3693, 10777, 10733, 10736, 10778, 10173, 13149, 10124, 10166, 8667, 10189, 8668, 10140, 13148, 8673, 10177, 8710, 8715, 8671, 13151, 8676, 10163, 10168, 6454, 6162, 6453, 10855, 11186.......

And it goes on and on for all the products in that category when the root menu item is clicked. Does anyone know how I can get the category pages to only query the items on the page, and do so individually every time someone clicks "next page"? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is interesting, Do you have any custom modules installed that would cause all products to be loaded in a single request? E.g. some form of lazy loading or infinite scroll?

Comment: I did have a module for AJAX pagination within the category, however I've disabled it a while ago, but still plagued with the issue. Even with AJAX pagination enabled, isn't the whole point of AJAX to pull data as needed (ie. querying the next 24 items via AJAX when clicking next button)?

So I presume this type of large query isn't normal on a stock Magento instance, even with large volumes of products?

Comment: You are correct. The point of AJAX is to load only the required resources at any one time reducing the overall time spent collecting data. However I have seen implementations that load all of the data and set `display:none` on a part of the container in HTML to appear to be loading more. I would try removing this module fully from your store so we can eliminate this as a possible cause for this issue.

Comment: So I've tried completely removing the AJAX layered nav/pagination plugin, but still getting the same issue. Below is the grid mode portion of my list.phtml design template:

http://pastebin.com/MsBcVxL9
I've skimmed over it, but wasn't able to find anything that could be causing the issue. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Also, in case you were interested, I was able to catch the query using mytop on our mysql node.

Comment: Grid looks fine, One way to test that is to revert design pack to base/default. What im more interested in is looking at the block from where `$_productCollection` is being generated. When I tested the collection is passed `setPageSize` to limit based on the of results to show per page and this was a stock 1.8 install. 

So next step is find the block and where the collection is being returned to see if it is being rewrote and extra functionality is being added.

Comment: So I tested by updating the category having the issues to use the default Magento template, and its still taking around 12-14 seconds to finish running that query. 

I've been looking at the code set to see if I can find any abnormalities in the blocks, but haven't found anything yet. Any other ideas on where to look? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with an exporter I wrote. Be careful with the method `getAllIds()` on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` I expected got get all `getLoadedIds()` instead I got *ALL* ids.

Answer (score 0):

Still having this issue?

Have you checked if there are any observers listening to the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` ?

This is fired in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml` method, and is a way for 3rd party extensions to potentially alter the product collection that was built, just before the html (your blocks) is generated.

grep all the installed extensions config.xml files for `catalog_block_product_list_collection`